# White noise generator for audio jamming ( from 250 Hz to 4.5 KHz )

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, pcb, embedded

I want to implement a white noise generator device for the purpose of audio 
recording jamming , 
as I can make the recorder record the noise and the speech together 
so any one try to record the speech , he/she will hear a noisy speech , 
But from where I should begin ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably a pink noise generator will be more suited to audio/speech. Have you tried googling?

Comment: Probably many recorded speech samples in different languages played over each other would be even more effective for confusing a speech recording. (I suspect most people do not have trouble in understanding speech when noise is present, unless the noise is extremely loud.) For this I think you do not (necessarily) have to do any electronic design, given that the required items are already commercial products.

Comment: Just curious: What is the scenario for the use of such a jammer? I.e. at what occasion and how is it used?

Comment: I like the elegance of the overlaid speech samples but if you need something a bit more heavy handed I would suggest music stereotypically associated with teenage boys. From experience; heavy metal, dubstep, drum and bass, etc all do an excellent job of masking speech. These genres have a large range of sounds with few pauses and as with the overlaid languages some of your brains processing power will be tempted into trying to find the pattern of the music.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the optimum spectrum for masking speech yet not sounding too unpleasant is a 'haystack' spectrum that mimics speech. White noise is more unpleasant than pink noise but neither apparently work all that well. Cambridge Sound Management makes their opinion fairly clear:

> Both white noise and pink noise are anything but unobtrusive, and neither is very
>   effective at blocking speech. Should a vendor attempt to convince you that his system is better
>   than another because it uses “pink” noise rather than “white” noise, run the other way, don’t walk.
>   Such a vendor is at best naïve, and more likely a borderline charlatan.

[image]

Keep in mind that the [document](http://cambridgesound.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Color-of-Noise.pdf) I lifted this from is intended to promote their products, but I think the principle is sound (no pun intended).

If you want to make white noise (which can be shaped into pink noise with a filter), the usual method is with a pseudo-random number generator. This can be a few CMOS chips or a small microcontroller. You might be able to do even better if you have a better processor by playing with speech samples. Of course if the samples or "white noise" are predictable it might be possible for someone to remove the noise.

Answer (score 1):

One of the techniques that used to work well for jamming microphones used for recording was to use two- high-frequency signals above 20 KHz (about 1 KHz apart) that beat together.  One or both of those frequencies was frequency-modulated with a noise signal.

The idea is that the frequencies mix together on the mic's diaphragm and thus create an audible masking noise that makes it impossible to record anything else that is a lower level.

This worked well for both dynamic and electret microphones.  I have no idea how well (or if at all) with modern MEMS microphones.

Answer (score 0):

Speech intelligibility is best measured around the SPL of the voice relative to the background noise at specific frequencies. In order to block speech, the best way is to blast noise ranging from 500Hz to 2kHz.

Turns out, we're really good at understanding someone even with high amounts of noise (or a fair amount of downsampling, etc). But if those specific frequencies are below the background noise (of what threshold I can't remember off the top of my head) then understanding the words spoken becomes much much harder.